Access function defined via python exec in class method
Consider the following code snippet:
class A:
    def hello(self):
        exec("def func():\n print('hello world')")
        func()

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

In the pdb shell, I create an instance of A and call hello:
(Pdb) aa = A()
(Pdb) aa.hello()
*** NameError: name 'func' is not defined

As shown, the code failed due to 'func' not defined.
However, when exec is outside of class method definition, it works.
(Pdb) exec("def func():\n print('hello world')")
(Pdb) func()
hello world

Why? How to make this work for the case where exec runs in a class method definition?

Modifying locals with exec is undefined behavior.

Could you elaborate? How am I modifying locals?

You're trying to create a local func variable with exec.

@user2357112 out of curiosity, so when globals is being modified it's fine? globals doesn't have the same warning as locals in the docs.

@BcK: Yeah, globals() can be modified safely.
